# Computing XNPV in Power BI based on specific starting date?

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to compute the NPV "Net Present Value" of a series of cash flows in PowerBI, using the XNPV formula, but want to be able to specify at which date the calculation should start.

I have 1 data table with 2 columns, "Month Ending", and "Value". The "Month Ending" column contains dates using the "Date" datatype, that are monthly for 40 years (following month end convention, I.E., 12/31/2022, 1/31/2023, 2/28/2023 etc...). The second column contains numbers of the data type "Fixed Decimal", representing the cash flow expected to occur in each monthly period. Additionally, I have a "What-If" parameter, of the "Decimal" data type, that can take a value between 0 and 1.

What I am able to do currently is compute the NPV of the entire cash flow series using the "XNPV" formula. What **I want to be able to do is specify the exact starting point that the XNPV calculation should begin at.**

Suppose we could create a parameter "Sale Date", that is is say 12/31/2024. **I want a formula that would tell me what the XNPV is on 12/31/2024, using all cash flows that occur after 12/31/2024.**

Ideally, I should be able to control this date using a slicer, and add it to a card on my display. **The goal is to have the user drag a slider for the "Sale Date", and to see the value update on the card visual in real time.** The end user should not have to modify any DAX expressions or Power Queries to change the result.

I have been struggling with this issue for a while, and cannot find any solutions that are dynamic in the way that I have described. Is what I am asking for even possible in PowerBI?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like all you need is a date dimension (calendar) table that you can use to filter your data table.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Not really sure what you mean, could you perhaps walk thru the steps in an answer to the Question? It's not enough that I add a filter to the table, I need it to be dynamic an controllable from the visualizations page.

Comment: Start here: https://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension

Comment: @AlexisOlson The solution you propose does not work. There is no way for me to Bond a M Query parameter to this table. I am trying to filter the raw data passed into the XNPV function. While this solution might work properly for a SUM, it doesn't work for XNPV.

Comment: You don't need to do anything like bonding a query parameter. If you have a standard calendar table with a relationship to your data table, then using a slicer on the calendar table automatically filters the data table and hence the raw values going into your XNPV calculation.

Comment: As I see now. I have to define a many to one relationship between the calendar's date's column, and my target tables date column, then use the slicer to filter the calendars date column. Thank you, I have been digging for a clear answer to this problem for a long time now